# How to know which modifier keys are which in X11?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xorg, xkb

I have X11R7-based desktop linux. I want to debug key modifiers of my keyboard. I have some left and right controls, alts, metas, etc., but for some reason (1) I'm not quite sure which is which from XKB point of view.

So, how do I debug modifiers on XKB keymaps?

(1) apple macbook + virtualbox + virtualized linux + X11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xev`!  This is an **X** **e**vent **v**iewer program.  Start it from a console and press your keys; it will register an event and give all kinds of juicy detail about what's going on.

The output looks like this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x2e, subw 0x0, time 122600873, (-49,299), root:(679,325),
    state 0x0, keycode 255 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0x2e, subw 0x0, time 122600971, (-49,299), root:(679,325),
    state 0x0, keycode 255 (keysym 0xffec, Super_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```